# php check if input value exists in mysql (related with performance)

Tags: php, mysql, session, cookies

In mysql data recorded, like: value1, value2, value3.

User enters data in input field. User may enter value1 or value2, or value3.

I want to check if user's input exists in mysql.

At page load need to connect to mysql, fetch data from mysql, create array, then use `in_array`.

As understand it is not good for performance at each page (re)load to connect to mysql and fetch the same data.

Data is not sensitive (not like passwords etc.).

From my opinion it would be reasonably to connect and fetch from mysql only one (first) time. Then store the data in some way that uses less resources.

What would be better solution (using less resources)? Sessions, cookies?

Comment: Selecting _all_ the data from the database is a wrong approach already. Use a WHERE clause to only select those records that match the user’s input.

Comment: I will select from one table (using WHERE). Plan that length of data would be not more than 1000 characters (in most cases, not more than 100 characters). How better to store the data?

Comment: As Donald Ervin Knuth said: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil (or at least most of it) in programming."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you said: "As understand it is not good for performance at each page (re)load to connect to mysql and fetch the same data."

For that reason you could use [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29). Using this  technique you can send data to, and retrieve data from, a server asynchronously. Also without reloading page.
Don't get messy back-end and front-end!

**Advantages of AJAX:**

- Traffic saving
- Reducing the load on the server
- Acceleration of the interface reaction
- Almost unlimited opportunities for interactive processing

Answer (score 1):

I'd create an object with every data of your table. Create that object at first time your website is openend and then carry the object over the pages using sessions.

With that you'll need only one DB load at startup to carry the data over and over your pages.

Comment: ... the session need to use only on two pages of the website. Seems either on the both pages (at end) need to create code that determines where user goes and if user goes to other pages, then unset session; or on all other pages, check if the session exists and if exists, then unset.